# How do I let my users create organic groups?

Tags: organic-groups

[n00b apologies] I have installed Organic Groups but am apparently too dumb to understand it.

How do I let me users create and administer their own groups? What do I need to do on the admin pages, and how do I add something on the main page to let them administer & join groups.

Sorry if this sounds dumb

---

Update: if they can't, and I have to - how do I add a "groups" item to the man menu and a sub-menu for each group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once you have enabled a "content type" as "group type" you can just let your users add new content of that type and it will create new groups.

It's explained very well in [this screen cast](http://modulesunraveled.com/organic-groups).

Comment: Thanks, I normally hate podcasts & screen casts, but this was wonderful. I am working my way through all 14 videos now.

Answer (score 1):

see documentation for Drupal 6 http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/og or Drupal 7 http://drupal.org/node/1114852.